# Update XML Document in WPF C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have got problems to update a XML Document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<test>
  <settings server="1" />
</test>
```

For example I want to update the "1".

I tried like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
doc.SelectSingleNode("test/settings/server").InnerText = "2"
doc.Save(path);
```

I think this should be easy to solve, but I am really a blockhead.

UPDATE:

I have tried your solutions and they work with the given example.
Thank you to all of you!

But in the given XML, there is a weird structure, I got problems with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<test>
  <settings server="1" />
  <settings config="999" />
</test>
```

With this structure none of your solutions work and i always get a "System.NullReferenceException" if I try to change the '999' of config.

I only can access the '1' of server.

Sorry, I didn't expected this and tried to keep the example as easy as possible.

Comment: xpath query queries for the element server. It is an attribute

Comment: I updated my answer with 2 ways of achieving this. I recommend you take a look at the last option which uses Linq to Xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with

```
var path = @"C:\users\bassie\desktop\test.xml";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
var settings = doc.SelectSingleNode("test/settings");
settings.Attributes["server"].Value = "2";
doc.Save(path);
```

`InnerText` would be used if you wanted to update `settings` to read something like:

```
<settings server="1"> 2 </settings>
```

Where you are trying to update an **attribute** of the `settings` element.

---

Regarding your update, you can replace `doc.SelectSingleNode` with `doc.SelectNodes` like so:

```
var settings = doc.SelectNodes("test/settings");
```

This will select all the available `settings` elements under `test`.

Then when setting the attribute you just provide the index of the element you want to target, e.g.:

```
settings[0].Attributes["server"].Value = "2";
```

to update the value of `server`, or

```
settings[1].Attributes["config"].Value = "000";
```

to update the value of `config`.

---

**However**

I think your best best here would be to use `System.Xml.Linq`, so that you can select the correct `settings` element by attribute name:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(path);
var attributeName = "server";

var element = document.Descendants("settings")
    .FirstOrDefault(el => el.Attribute(attributeName) != null);
```

That code gets all `settings` elements (`Descendants`) in the document, and then selects the first one where the `attributeName` ("server" in this case) is not `null`.

This of course relies on the fact that each attribute only appear once (i.e. you can't have multiple `settings` elements with the "server" attribute), as it uses the `FirstOrDefault` selector meaning it will only return 1 element.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the perfect solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

*server* is an attribute

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
doc.SelectSingleNode("test/settings").Attributes["server"].Value = "2"
doc.Save(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.Load(path); 
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement; 
XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode("test/settings"); 
myNode.Attributes["server"].Value = "2";
doc.Save(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693062.aspx)

```
var document = XDocument.Load(path);
document.Descendants("settings").First().Attribute("server").Value = "2";
document.Save(path);
```